# Scala one-liner to generate MD5 Hash from string

Tags: scala, hash, md5

I'm new to Scala and I found this interesting one-liner to generate a hex-encoded MD5 hash from a string. I was hoping someone could help me understand this better.

```
private def getMd5(inputStr: String): String = {
  val md: MessageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")
  md.digest(inputStr.getBytes()).map(0xFF & _).map { "%02x".format(_) }.foldLeft("") {_ + _}
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: The best way to understand this is to start with an input string in the REPL and follow through each line or operation and inspect the output. Let's say `val inputStr = "foo"`  The `map` calls transform the value on the left with given operation. The `foldLeft` will concatenate the collection of strings given as input. e.g. `["foo", "bar", "baz"]` becomes `"foobarbaz"`

Comment: Seems rather inefficient using 2 `map`s and a `foldLeft` to do what can be accomplished with a single `foldLeft`.

Comment: @jwvh - how would you improvise it?

Comment: `md.digest(inputStr.getBytes()).foldLeft("")(_+"%02x".format(_))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a analogue to this java code but without StringBuilder (it's up to you)

```
    MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
    String password = "secret";
    messageDigest.update(password.getBytes());
    byte[] bytes = messageDigest.digest();
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte aByte : bytes) {
        stringBuilder.append(Integer.toString((aByte & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
    }
    System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
```

Let's consider second line:

```
md.digest(inputStr.getBytes()).map(0xFF & _).map { "%02x".format(_) }.foldLeft("") {_ + _}
```

1. md.digest(inputStr.getBytes()) ---- take bytes from String
2. md.digest(inputStr.getBytes()).**map(0xFF & _)** --- bitwise & with every item of array (map return a new array)
3. md.digest(inputStr.getBytes()).map(0xFF & *).**map { "%02x".format(***) } map with formatting each item.
4. md.digest(inputStr.getBytes()).map(0xFF & *).map { "%02x".format(*) }.**foldLeft("") {_ + _}** it's typical fold, in our case starting from left and init value "", (if it will be easier for you, it's "far" analogue of StringBuilder behaving in above example). I recommend you to read about fold, reduce and etc. actions in scala. e.g. https://coderwall.com/p/4l73-a/scala-fold-foldleft-and-foldright

Comment: just to clarify the above: step 2 converts `Byte` to `Int` (which isn't actually necessary, since `"%02x".format(_)` will convert bytes as well). step 3 just converts an `Int` to the hex representation of that number (and works on bytes too). 

really, all the MD5 work is being done by the `digest` function. scala isn't doing anything special here.

Comment: step 2 converts **every** item of an array to  byte with bitwise &, (0xFF - because it's byte size in hex), and step 3 converts that value to hex. Maybe it's more clear

Comment: if it was helpful, please mark this post as answered, please.